# How to make a horizontal view without using grid and flex

Tags: css, reactjs

I am struggling now because of making a sliding bar.

I want to fix the horizontal view without using a grid and flex. I have fixed-width spans that are going to overflow in a horizontal view but I will hide the overflow part. When I click a button it will show the spans one by one. That's my use case.

I have the following files:

**App.js:**

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className={"spanContainer"}>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
        <span>5</span>
        <span>6</span>
        <span>7</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**index.js:**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

**styles.css:**

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.spanContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  width: 213px;
  height: 62px;
  display: block;
}
```

[Here's a codesandbox of my sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-leftpad-x6jpj)

I edit my sample code. The problem is I am using `inline-box` but don't know how well it is supported in all major browsers, is there a way to find this out?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: [inline-box doesn't have much default support](https://caniuse.com/#search=inline-box)

You can find which browsers support a given feature using [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/)

Comment: thanks for the answer. every browser does not support the inline-box then how can I align horizontally every span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the css file to the following:

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.spanContainer {
  width: calc(400px * 7);
  overflow-x: auto;
}

span {
  float:left;
  width: 400px;
  height: 62px;
}
```

which results in the 7 spans lined up left to right. You can continue from here to add javascript and a button to do whatever else you want with the spans.

Comment: and also thanks for editing my code. I will keep it.